# Crystal Reports objects disposal

Tags: c#, .net, iis, crystal-reports

We are facing issue while disposing crystal reports objects. Currently we are disposing crystal reports objects on page unload which deletes respective crystal report files from windows temp folder but at the same time we have noticed that on average temp files of 15 reports per day keeps on incrementing in temp folder which means that due to some reason report objects are not getting disposed properly. This leads to "Load report failed" error after a few days.

One reason could be the network failure due to which object disposal call back can't do its job.

Question is that is there any way we could dispose old crystal report objects from server through a `script` a `batch` or some `IIS configuration` to avoid `Load report failed` error for which we have to reset our IIS.

Comment: You can tweak system registry. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CRYSTAL DECISIONS\10.0\REPORT APPLICATION SERVER\SERVER\PrintJobLimit (Ver 13.0) HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Business Objects\Suite 12.0\Report Application Server\InprocServer\PrintJobLimit (Ver 12.0). Change the "PrintJobLimit".